# text input field as jQuery datepicker default date

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, default

The default date for jQuery's datepicker is the current date, but I need it to be the pre-populated date from my `#start_date` input field.

This is where I'm at now but it doesn't work.

```
var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
$('.datepicker').datepicker("option", "defaultDate", start_date);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" class="datepicker form-control col-sm-6" placeholder="Start" value="<?php (!empty($row['start_date'])?$row['start_date']:'');?>>
```

Comment: `The default date for jQuery's datepicker is the current date` this is not the case. Assuming the value of the input field is in a format which can be parsed as a `Date()` that is what will be used as the default value. If it isn't a valid `Date()`, then it defaults to today.

Comment: What is the value of `$row['start_date']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the input field date is the same format which set in the input field when you pick the date, then it will be loaded by Datepicker by default without any javascript code just Datepicker intalization.

may be your variable  $row['start_date']  show date and time in input field try to make the value in the format of mm/dd/yyyy and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
$('.datepicker').datepicker("option", "defaultDate", new Date(start_date));
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming that it's possible to use a form input value as the default picker date.