# Spotfire - advanced row level security

Tags: spotfire

I'm working on row level security in Spotfire (6.5) report.

It should be implemented on 3 levels, lets call it L1, L2 and L3. There is additional mapping table that contains Userlogins and specified values on all levels where user has access. Additionaly if user is not in mapping table he is some kind of Root user so he has access to everything.

On DB side it looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE SECURITY
(
  USER_ID VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, L1 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, L2 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, L3 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
--, L1L2L3 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) -- option there could be one column that contains lowest possible level
);

INSERT INTO SECURITY (USER_ID, L1) VALUES ('UNAME1','A');
INSERT INTO SECURITY (USER_ID, L2) VALUES ('UNAME2','BB');
INSERT INTO SECURITY (USER_ID, L3) VALUES ('UNAME3','CCC');

CREATE TABLE SECURED_DATA
(
  L1 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, L2 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, L3 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
, V1 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO SECURED_DATA (L1, V1) VALUES ('A',1);
INSERT INTO SECURED_DATA (L1, L2, V1) VALUES ('B','BB',2);
INSERT INTO SECURED_DATA (L1, L2, L3, V1) VALUES ('C','CC','CCC',3);
```

Finally I've made Information Link and then I've changed its' sql code to something like that:

```
SELECT
  M.*
FROM
  SECURITY S
INNER JOIN SECURED_DATA M
ON
  (
    M.L1     = S.L1
  AND S.USER_ID = (%CURRENT_USER%)
  )
UNION ALL
SELECT
  M.*
FROM
  SECURITY S
INNER JOIN SECURED_DATA M
ON
  (
    M.L2   = S.L2
  AND S.USER_ID = (%CURRENT_USER%)
  )
UNION ALL
SELECT
  M.*
FROM
  SECURITY S
INNER JOIN SECURED_DATA M
ON
  (
    M.L3      = S.L3
  AND S.USER_ID = (%CURRENT_USER%)
  )
UNION ALL
SELECT
  M.*
FROM
  SECURED_DATA M
WHERE
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(1)
    FROM
      SECURITY S
    WHERE S.USER_ID = (%CURRENT_USER%)
  )
  =0
```

It works fine, but I'm worndering if there is more smart and more Spotfire way to get it?

Many thanks and regards,
Maciej

Answer (score 0):

My guess on "more smart and more Spotfire way" is that you want to be able to cache a single data set and use it for multiple users, limiting it in the analytic rather than in the data pull.  There is some danger to this, if we're doing it for security's sake, because the data will technically be in the analytic, and if they have permission to edit and add visualizations, you no longer control what they can and cannot see.  **If there's any authoring allowed in Web Player for the specific analytic, I recommend all securities be done DataBase-side.**

If you want to do it in Spotfire anyways, here is my recommendation:

Have an Information Link (for example case, named IL_SecurityCheck) which is Select * from SECURITY WHERE S.USER_ID = (%CURRENT_USER%).

If they move from a cover page to the page with the data in it, you can put the code in the script to change pages; if not, you can use a method I explained here: [Spotfire Current Date in input field with calendar popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453648/spotfire-current-date-in-input-field-with-calendar-popup/36342420#36342420)  to fire off a script on open.

Button Script required:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

crossSource = Document.Data.Tables["IL_SecurityCheck"]

rowCount = crossSource.RowCount
rowIndexSet = IndexSet(rowCount, True)

print rowCount
#rowCount = Document.Data.Tables["Managed Care UpDownStream"].RowCount
colCurs = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(crossSource.Columns["L1"])
colCurs2 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(crossSource.Columns["L2"])
colCurs3 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(crossSource.Columns["L3"])

x = ""
if rowIndexSet.IsEmpty != True:
    for row in crossSource.GetRows(rowIndexSet, colCurs):
        if colCurs.CurrentValue is not None:
            x += "[L1] = '" + colCurs.CurrentValue + "' and "
    for row in crossSource.GetRows(rowIndexSet, colCurs2):
        if colCurs2.CurrentValue is not None:
            x += "[L2] = '" + colCurs2.CurrentValue + "' and "
    for row in crossSource.GetRows(rowIndexSet, colCurs3):
        if colCurs3.CurrentValue is not None:
            x += "[L3] = '" + colCurs3.CurrentValue + "' and "  
    x = x[:len(x) - 4]
else:
    x = "1=1"

Document.Properties["SecurityLimits"] = x
```

Visualization Data Limited by Expression: ${SecurityLimits}